# Prevent Mac from sleeping when lid is closed

Tags: macbook, sleep, updates

I am doing a Software Update on my Mac and I would like to close its lid. But closing the lid lulls it to sleep and cuts off the Internet connection.

How do I prevent my MacBook Pro from sleeping when the lid is closed? The display should be turned off at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display can be turned off by decreasing the brightness all way down to zero.  Additionally, the display can also be quickly turned off by pressing the key combination, `Shift-Control-Eject` (*this is the Eject key on the top right, above the delete key on the MacBook keyboard*).  Closing the lid is not necessary.

I also use this [Jiggler](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html) application to prevent my MacBook from sleeping when I have a big download to fetch and can't afford to sit in front of the laptop.

Comment: What about when I need to close the lid - e.g. to stop kids/dogs/cats etc. messing with my laptop when I'm not there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of a couple of programs that do what you're looking for:

- [SleepLess ($9.50)](http://www.alxsoft.com/mac/sleepless.html)
- [InsomniaX (free)](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo)